# Call lua function from bash

Tags: bash, lua, pipe

I have a lua-script, named "program.lua".
I start this script as 'lua /path/to/program.lua' and I get specific CLI provided by the script:

```lua
bash $ /usr/bin/lua /path/to/program.lua
Usage: 
  help   - help
  quit   - quit
  do_get - get data
script> _
```

In this script I have function 'do_get', and if I call this function from the program.lua's CLI, I've got the correct output:

```lua
bash $ /usr/bin/lua /path/to/program.lua
Usage: 
  help   - help
  quit   - quit
  do_get - get data
script> do_get
string1
string2
param1
param2

script> _
```

The question. How I can call function 'do_get' from bash and get the output I need without entering to script's CLI?

The script edit is disallowed.

Thank you

Comment: This isn't really a Lua question, as you're not changing the Lua script. Also, what you're calling isn't a *function* in the Lua sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the output by calling the Lua Program in a shell-script and [pipe the output to a variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/338000/bash-assign-output-of-pipe-to-a-variable):

```
lua_output=$(printf "do_get\n\n" | /usr/bin/lua /path/to/program.lua 2>&1)
 
echo $lua_output
```

If that does not work try a tool that can handle interactive prompts like yes (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/yes.1.html) `yes do_get | /usr/bin/lua /path/to/program.lua` or `expect` (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/expect.1.html)

Comment: No. I've edited the question and provided more information why I can't launch the script directly from the bash

Comment: @AndriiK. ok, i've upodated my answer

Comment: @AndriiK. did you try running the example?

Comment: @AndriiK. i've updated the answer, you need to handle the interavtive prompt. Try to pipe  or a tool like `yes` or `expect`, `expect` will work.